# Is the duality pairing $\langle \phi, \psi \rangle_{H^{1/2}\times H^{-1/2}}$ simply the $L^2$ inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $H^s: = H^s([0,2\pi])$ be the (periodic) Sobolev space on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with the norm $|| \cdot ||_{H^s([0,2\pi])}$ given by
$$
||\phi||_{H^s} := \bigg(\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}(1+|n|^{2s})|\hat \phi_n|^2\bigg)^{1/2},
$$
where $\{\hat \phi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ are the Fourier coefficients of $\phi$.

Is the duality pairing between $H^{-1/2}$ and $H^{1/2}$ always just the regular $L^2$ inner product? I.e, for $\phi \in H^{1/2}$ and $\psi \in H^{-1/2}$ is
$$
\langle \phi, \psi \rangle_{H^{1/2}\times H^{-1/2}} = \int_0^{2\pi}\phi(x) \overline{\psi(x)} dx = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\hat \phi_n \ \overline{\hat \psi_n},
$$
or do we need some extra conditions for this to hold? In what situations can we identify the duality pairing and the $L^2$ inner product?

Comment: $H^{-1/2}$ is not defined the way you write it. This is only valid for $s>0$. In general, the elements in $H^{-1/2}$ are not functions but functionals.

Comment: For periodic Sobolev spaces, the norm stated above for $H^{-1/2}$ is equivalent to the usual definition of the  $H^{-1/2}$ norm. See, for instance Eq. (3.83) of Fourier Analysis and Partial Differential Equations by Rafael Jose Iorio.

Comment: Actually, Eq. (3.86) in that book seems to answer my question.

Comment: Eq. (3.86) in that book says that the duality pairing is indeed the same as what I have written above.